# Slicing a multiindexed column dataframe to obtain a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

```
import pandas as pd
import string

from random import randint

months                  = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ]
monthyAmounts           = [ "actual", "budgeted", "difference" ]

summary = []

summary.append( [ randint( -1000, 15000 ) for x in range( 0, len( months ) * len( monthyAmounts ) ) ] )
summary.append( [ randint( -1000, 15000 ) for x in range( 0, len( months ) * len( monthyAmounts ) ) ]  )
summary.append( [ randint( -1000, 15000 ) for x in range( 0, len( months ) * len( monthyAmounts ) ) ]  )

index   = pd.Index( [ 'Income', 'Expenses', 'Difference' ], name = 'type' )
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [months, monthyAmounts], names=['month', 'category'] )

summaryDF = pd.DataFrame( summary, index = index, columns = columns )

budgetMonths = pd.date_range( "January, 2018", periods = 12, freq = 'BM' )

idx = pd.IndexSlice
budgetDifference = summaryDF.loc[ 'Difference', idx[:, 'budgeted' ] ].cumsum()
budgetActual     = summaryDF.loc[ 'Difference', idx[:, 'actual' ] ].cumsum()
```

What I want is a dataframe containing just the actual & budgeted columns for the Difference row per month and an additional column containing the months (I need this additional column for graph generation eventually)

If I do just:

```
budgetDifference = pd.DataFrame( { 'difference' : budgetDifference, 'months' : budgetMonths } )
```

what I end up with is a dataframe with the difference & month columns.

```
                    difference  months
month   category        
Jan budgeted        1097        2018-01-31
Feb budgeted        11476       2018-02-28
Mar budgeted        11143       2018-03-30
Apr budgeted        25082       2018-04-30
May budgeted        28019       2018-05-31
Jun budgeted        37164       2018-06-29
Jul budgeted        36747       2018-07-31
Aug budgeted        44651       2018-08-31
Sep budgeted        54283       2018-09-28
Oct budgeted        62728       2018-10-31
Nov budgeted        76144       2018-11-30
Dec budgeted        77781       2018-12-31
```

However, when I try:

```
budgetDifference = pd.DataFrame( { 'difference' : budgetDifference, 'actual' : budgetActual, 'months' : budgetMonths } )
```

I get:

```
ValueError: array length 12 does not match index length 24
```

and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to align indices for the series which constitute your dataframe:

```
res = pd.DataFrame({'difference': budgetDifference,
                    'months': budgetMonths,
                    'actual': pd.Series(budgetActual.values, index=budgetDifference.index)})

print(res)

                difference     months  actual
month category                               
Jan   budgeted        4057 2018-01-31    1592
Feb   budgeted        4550 2018-02-28    2211
Mar   budgeted        3847 2018-03-30    4096
Apr   budgeted       12970 2018-04-30    9588
May   budgeted       17459 2018-05-31   19623
Jun   budgeted       30884 2018-06-29   32347
Jul   budgeted       35258 2018-07-31   37205
Aug   budgeted       35823 2018-08-31   50234
Sep   budgeted       47599 2018-09-28   57188
Oct   budgeted       61258 2018-10-31   71096
Nov   budgeted       65914 2018-11-30   71904
Dec   budgeted       73814 2018-12-31   77308
```

Comment: To make it a bit cleaner as well, I dumped the multiindex for the rows and just did pd.DataFrame( {'difference': pd.Series( budgetDifference.values, index = budgetMonths ),
                                  'months'    : budgetMonths,
                                  'actual'    : pd.Series( budgetActual.values, index = budgetMonths ) } )